# LoadToFile issue when trying to load .txt file into a string

Tags: delphi, access-violation, text-files

After my previous question of `SavingToFile` with `TStringList`, I now need to load the file I created called `Password.txt` using `LoadFromFile` but I don´t know what the form of `LoadFromFile` is. The `Password.txt` is in the same folder as the program that needs to load it but I keep getting `Access Violation` at different addresses when I try `LoadToFile` in the way I thought it would work. How to I load `Password.txt` to a string in Delphi without getting a violation ?

Please help

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
var
  StringList: TStringList;
...
  StringList := TStringList.Create;
  try
    StringList.LoadFromFile('myfile.txt');
    //do stuff with StringList
  finally
    StringList.Free;
  end;
```

You are probably forgetting to create the string list properly with code like this:

```
StringList.Create;//don't do this
```

or

```
StringList.LoadFromFile('myfile.txt');//must create StringList first
```

But without seeing your code all we can do is guess as to what your problem is. That said, the first sample of code above is correct.

Comment: Ahhh I forgot "StringList := TStringList.Create;" . Thanks for the help :)

Comment: It's a mistake that every Delphi programmer has made at least once!! Join the club!

Comment: Nyt, didn't the compiler warn you about using an uninitialized variable? Never ignore a compiler warning.

Comment: @TLama : It said I needed 15 rep to be able to accept an answer on my first question but now I have 235 rep so I can :)

Comment: @Rob Kennedy : It didnt warn me . It only gave me an access violation error

Comment: @Nyt you can always accept answers. What you need 15 rep for is to vote up. You can now do both!

Comment: @Rob It was probably at the tail end of a method which had already used the variable in order to save the file.

Comment: Spelling mistake on my part in the one comment , its not 235 rep its 25 :p